# Connecting to Home Network remotely using DD-WRT

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt

I recently started travelling alot and find myself requiring to connect to my home network for resources and would like to set up OpenVPN on my DD-WRT as a server and connect remotely from my Windows laptop while I'm travelling. I have a dual network setup with Verizon FIOS being the ISP with their modem/router combo and an internal router running DD-WRT that all of my resources are connected to.

Can this be done?

Comment: Try first to connect with Verizon and see if that works. You may possibly have set up a double NAT setup with the extra router that makes connection dificult.

Comment: Yes.  Do you have a static IP address, failing which a world routable one?  Are you sure you mren "dual network"? ( ie 2 Internet connections? If so that can make things hard) or did you mean your FIOS device passes all traffic on to dd-wrt?